# How to pack Boolean operations using gcc or other compilers?

Tags: gcc, compilation, vectorization, auto-vectorization

Intel CPUs are capable of [performing 512 or 1024 bitwise operations](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-intel-advanced-vector-extensions) using vectorized operations. Assume I have a snippet of code that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    _Bool i0, i1, i2, i3, w0, w1, w2, w3, w4;

    i0 = 1;
    i1 = 1;
    i2 = 0;
    i3 = 0;

    w0 = i0 & i1;
    w1 = i1 & i2;
    w2 = i0 & i3;

    w3 = w0 & w1;
    w4 = w1 & w2;

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", i0, i1, i2, i3);
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", w0, w1, w2, w3, w4);

    return 0;
}
```

Does `GCC` or Intel compiler vectorize this code automatically or I need to rewrite the code to be able to benefit from vectorization? Ideally, I would like the first three operations to be performed in parallel and then, the next two computed in parallel.

Comment: What are the types of `i0`, ...? How do you obtain them? Provide a [mre]!

Comment: It might, but you would have to verify this is the case by examining the assembler code once you have compiled it. You can also just use the AVX functions directly from within C++ if available as shown in your link.

Comment: @chtz I have updated the code to include more information.
I understand that a `_Bool` takes a byte instead of a single bit. What I'm looking for is whether the compiler will pack these `_Bool` variables to process them using vectorized operations. Ideally, one would hope the Boolean variables will consume only a single bit when packed.

Comment: In your example every value is known at compile time and compilers are generally capable of detecting this (at least for simple examples like your code). Give a more realistic example where booleans are either loaded from memory or are results of operations like comparisons. But with your simple example the overhead of decomposing any vectorized results for passing it to `printf` would outweigh any potential benefit.